# Expandable RecyclerView with Firestore. How to make it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

I have problem with implementing expandable RecyclerView to my project. I don't know why but my app just don't responding on clicking on `cardView` I will be very grateful if you look at my code and write what I can fix if you find some error in it. So first 
...

```
public NoteHolder(View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
           textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_description);
           textViewPriority = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_priority);
           itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   int position = getAdapterPosition();
                   if (position != NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                       listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                   }
               }

           });
       }
   }
```

in my `NoteHolder` is set `listener` with `onItemClick` on it. So let's look on `onItemClick` method in HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {...

FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>()
                .setQuery(query, Note.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new NoteAdapter(options);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = RootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //DetailView
        View CardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_item, container, false);
        final ConstraintLayout cardView = CardView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new NoteAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {

                Note note = documentSnapshot.toObject(Note.class);
                int pathInt = position;
                constraintLayout = cardView.findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout);
                String path =String.valueOf(pathInt);
                 if(possition != NO_POSSITION) {
                     Animation slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_out_top);
                     constraintLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                     //adding sliding effect
                     constraintLayout.startAnimation(slideDown);
                 }
            }
        });
```

> **if (possition != NO_POSSITION) {...}**

this `if` is executed, I tried put in it `Log.d` and it displayed expected message.